# Recursion code in series of 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I tried to make a C program in which the problem is:
  x = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 ....

The stop condition is when the value of "x" is calculated in the previous interaction is less than 0.0001

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float recursion( float n ){

    int f = 0 , i = 1;
    float calc = 4;

    f = i%2;

    if (calc == 0.0001)
        return 0;


        if ( f != 0 ){
            calc += recursion (4/n) - recursion (4/n+2);
            n += 2;
        }
            else
                calc += recursion (4/n) + recursion (4/n+2);
                n+=2;

            return calc;
}
int main(){

    float n , result;

    cout << "Enter the value of N" ;
    cin >> n;

    result = recursion (n);

    cout << "The value of N is ..." << result ;
}
```

I tried to get an accountant to change the sign "+" to "-" or "-" to "+".
I do not know why codito not working. Any help is welcome

Comment: Are you missing a set of braces (brackets) in the `else' clause?

Comment: `calc` is always 4 when reaching `if (calc == 0.0001)` so it will never cause a return

Comment: Additionally, `i` is always `1` and so is `f`.

Comment: I see another error: should be `4/(n+2)`

Comment: This seems easier with a `for` loop rather than recursion.  With recursion, you have very limited accuracy for PI.

Comment: The sum of the infinite series 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7... is π/4, so you could just have put `result = 0.7853981634 * n;`

Comment: Unfortunately this converges far too slowly to be usable, e.g. after a few iterations each new term is nearly as large as the last. Thankfully there are similar power series with far better results  (e.g. atan 1 = 4*atan 1/5 - atan 1/239)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think recursion is necessary.  This is easily solved with iteration.
I see the following pattern.  The denominator is 1,3,5,7- odd numbers.  That's i%2.
The sign of the fraction is alternating between + and -.  Use the modulus 2 of the iteration to multiply the current fraction by -1 or not.  Then += to the running sum.

Comment: thanks for the help, for he had already done interactively, this problem started putting me to do recursive, and I'm a new student in the area of programming

Answer (score 0):

See my comments inline:

```
float recursion( float n ){

    int f = 0 , i = 1;
    float calc = 4;

    f = i%2;
    // this if condition will never succeed so you have infinite recursion
    // so you will end with stack overflow
    if (calc == 0.0001)
        return 0;


    if ( f != 0 ){
        calc += recursion (4/n) - recursion (4/n+2);
        n += 2;
    }
        else
            calc += recursion (4/n) + recursion (4/n+2);
            n+=2;

        return calc;
```

}

the solution to your problem is that you make the function takes two parameters first parameter as it is and the second parameters should be `calc` of the caller.

Comment: The funny thing is that you came to stack overflow asking about a stack over flow exception :D

Answer (score 0):

1. In this code segment:

   ```
   int f = 0 , i = 1;
   float calc = 4;

   f = i%2;
   ```

   f is always 1. I don't know what you wanted to achive with this, but it may be wrong.
2. Avoid using exact comparisons when using floating-point values. As they are rounded, the comparision may fail and you have no idea way. Instead, use

   ```
   if (calc <= 0.0001)
   ```
3. Also, the way you are computing the sum is wrong. You do not have to use recursion to compute 4/n, for example.
4. `recursion (4/n+2)` should have been `recursion (4/(n+2))`, because of the operator precedence, but, anyway, it is wrong in this form.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first step when doing a recursive problem is to write out your iterative step, and the conditional at which you will stop recursing.

Let's look at a function declaration:

```
float recursion(float n) { ... }
```

It sounds like your last iteration will be when:

```
(4. / n) - (4. / (n+2)) < 0.0001
```

And at each step, it looks like you want to add that delta to the total:

```
total += (4. / n) - (4. / (n+2))
```

So let's start:

```
float recursion(int n) {

    // Calculate the delta at each step...
    const float delta = (4./n - 4./(n+2));

    // If the delta is less than our tolerance, then we __don't__ recurse.
    // Depending on the requirements of your algorithm, you might return 0 here, 
    // or delta as I have.
    if (delta < 0.0001)
        return delta;

    // Otherwise, we should recurse.
    return delta + recursion(n+4);
}
```

We could also implement this very easily as a loop instead of recursion. It's often helpful to do that to see the iteration process more clearly.

```
float iterative() {
    int n = 1;
    float total = 0;

    while (true) {
        // Calculate the delta at each step...
        const float delta = (4./n - 4./(n+2));

        // If the delta is less than our tolerance, then we are done!
        if (delta < 0.0001)
            return total + delta;

        // Otherwise, update the total and keep iterating.
        total += delta;
        n += 4;
     }
}
```

Some things to note:

- In C, you need to be careful about integer division versus floating point division. In your code, you're fine because `n` is a float. In my code, I've changed `n` to be an integer, so I'm using `4.` instead of `4`, because that will be interpreted by the compiler as a `double float` (also known as a `double`), instead of as an integer.
- I'm iterating / recursing each time by 4. If you can't see why, then look at how much math is being done at each iteration.
- We only pass the denominator (which you named `n`) to each recursive function. Naming your variables better can help make this more clear.

Comment: thanks for the help, for he had already done interactively, this problem started putting me to do recursive, and I'm a new student in the area of programming

Answer (score 0):

The sequence you want to evaluate converges towards pi. This sequence arises when you consider Taylor development of `arctan` function at `x=1`, therefore `arctan(1)=pi/4`:

[image: arctan]

Unfortunately this expansion does not converge very fast (think that all odd monoms are equal to 1, so you are loosing their convergence power). There is better ways to assess decimals of pi.

Anyway, as stated before, recursion should not be used to solve this kind of problem. In fact recursion should be only used in few cases. Eg.: When you can prove that a divide and conquer algorithm reduce the complexity of the task you want to perform. **In your case it does not at all, so avoid it.** You will just fill up - and maybe overflow - your `call stack` without necessity. As pointed out by others your problem can be solved with a classic loop.

You may solve it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main(void) {

   double x0 = 0.0;
   double x1 = 0.0;
   double eps = 0.0001;
   double s = 1.0;
   int i = 0;
   int maxiter = 100000;

   do {
      // Save Previous Term in order to compare with the next:
      x0 = x1;
      // Compute Next Term:
      x1 += s*4.0/(2*static_cast<double>(i)+1);
      // Change Sign:
      s *= -1.0;
      // Increase Counter:
      i++;
      // Log:
      std::cout << std::setw(6) << i << std::fixed << "\t"
                << x1 << "\t" << std::setw(10) << (x1-x0) << std::endl;
    // Loop until convergence criterion is met or max iteration is reached:
    } while((std::abs(x1-x0)>eps)&&(i<maxiter));

    return 0;
}
```

If you do not know how many steps it will take to converge you need a `loop` instead of a `for` statement. In your case, `loop` is not necessary since you can write down the difference between two consecutive terms and determine how many steps it requires to be small enough with respect to your epsilon criterion.

Anyway, if you use a loop you have to make sure that:

- Loop will ever exit at some point (avoid endless loop) ;
- When exiting, the result is correct.

This is the reason why I use two criteria in my loop condition. The second is not necessary since I can show that distance between two consecutive terms vanishes to `0` as `i` grows. But I might want the loop stops before I reached some iteration threshold.